# Pretending to be another user with Flask

Tags: flask, flask-login

When I need to get information about the current logged in user in a flask web app, I import `current_user` like this:

```
from flask_login import current_user
```

And then I use some attributes, for example `current_user.role` to determine the type of user, or `current_user.username`, and based e.g. on the username I can also access the DB data and user settings associated with that particular user.

In order to provide a better support to specific users having specific issues, I am realising that it could be useful to "impersonate" them, that is logging in with my admin account but then pretending to be them instead.

I have seen this being done successfully on some legacy systems I do not own (but maintained by me), and I think it's very useful when inspecting issues.

An attempt I would have in mind is "overriding" `current_user` if an admin (like me) chooses a new impersonation function that I could implement. Or replacing `current_user` with some adapter class or with something that implements a common interface.

Or perhaps Flask, and in particular Flask-Login, already provides a mechanism to do this? I tried to look online in the Flask documentation with no success. Do you have any advice?

Comment: You want to login into your flask app as a regular user "when inspecting issues"? I create a testuser account with no admin rights to accomplish this.

Comment: Many thanks @AlvinCruz , but what I meant is that sometimes issues only occur with some specific user accounts because those particular accounts have a very specific combination of configurations and/or data that causes those issues. Therefore just "impersonating" that account, i.e. pretending to be that specific user, would be much easier than trying to find a way to reproduce the problem by ourselves from scratch with a testuser, or forcing the real user to be involved in the inspections and in all the related tests.